# Transfer interaction of UIScrollView to another UIScrollView mid-scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have an interface with the following structure, with names for important elements in brackets:

```
- UIViewController
      - UIScrollView (ScrollViewA)
           - UIViewController (ProfileOverviewViewController)
           - UIViewController (ProfileDetailViewController)
               - UICollectionView (ScrollViewB)
```

So essentially there is a vertical scroll view (`ScrollViewB`) inside another vertical scroll view (`ScrollViewA`). `ProfileOverviewViewController` and `ProfileDetailViewController` are both the size of the device screen, so `ScrollViewB` is only visible once `ScrollViewA` is scrolled to the bottom.

Pagination is enabled on `ScrollViewA`, so snaps to either `ProfileOverviewViewController` taking the whole screen view or `ProfileDetailViewController` taking the whole screen view.

Hopefully this graphic makes the layout a bit more clear:
[image: Layout]

My question is:

- If the user scrolls to the bottom of `ScrollViewA` so that `ProfileDetailViewController` and `ScrollViewB` is visible.
- The user scrolls down a bit on `ScrollViewB` then releases.
- Then the user scrolls up on `ScrollViewB`.
- Whilst still holding down the finger, when the user reaches the top of the content in `ScrollViewB`, `ScrollViewB` should stop scrolling and the `ScrollViewA` should start scrolling up towards `ProfileOverviewViewController`, all within the same finger gesture from the user.

Instead of at the moment where `ScrollViewB` will simply extend to a negative y content offset since `bounces` property is true.

**How can I transfer the scrolling of ScrollViewB to ScrollViewA when it reaches the top?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your hierarchy is so much messy. if you tell us what is UI looks like or whats your final output then might be we give you better suggestions to maintain the view hierarchies.

Comment: It should work Automatic see player screen of -> https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/luxe-radio/id1073120504?mt=8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a pretty good question & I had to dig a little to find a suitable solution. Here is the commented code. The idea is to add a custom pan gesture to scrollViewB & set the ProfileDetailViewController as its gesture delegate. 
When the panning brings scrollViewB to its top, the ProfileOverviewViewController gets warned & starts scrolling scrollViewA. When the user releases its finger ProfileOverviewViewController decides wether to scroll to the bottom or top of the content.

Hope it helps :)

ProfileDetailViewController :

```
//
//  ProfileDetailViewController.swift
//  Sandbox
//
//  Created by Eric Blachère on 23/12/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Eric Blachère. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

protocol OverflowDelegate: class {
    func onOverflowEnded()
    func onOverflow(delta: CGFloat)
}

/// State of overflow of scrollView
///
/// - on: The scrollview is overflowing : ScrollViewA should take the lead. We store the last trnaslation of the gesture
/// - off: No overflow detected
enum OverflowState {
    case on(lastRecordedGestureTranslation: CGFloat)
    case off

    var isOn: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .on:
            return true
        case .off:
            return false
        }
    }
}

class ProfileDetailViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollviewB: UIScrollView!

    weak var delegate: OverflowDelegate?

    /// a pan gesture added on scrollView B
    var customPanGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    /// The state of the overflow
    var overflowState = OverflowState.off

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a custom pan gesture recognizer added on scrollview B. This way we can be delegate of this gesture & follow the finger
        customPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panRecognized(gesture:)))
        scrollviewB.addGestureRecognizer(customPanGesture)
        customPanGesture.delegate = self

        scrollviewB.delegate = self
    }


    @objc func panRecognized(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch overflowState {
        case .on(let lastRecordedGestureTranslation):
            // the user just released his finger
            if gesture.state == .ended {
                print("didEnd !!")
                delegate?.onOverflowEnded() // warn delegate
                overflowState = .off // end of overflow
                scrollviewB.panGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true // enable scroll again
                return
            }

            // compute the translation delta & send it to delegate
            let fullTranslationY = gesture.translation(in: view).y
            let delta = fullTranslationY - lastRecordedGestureTranslation
            overflowState = .on(lastRecordedGestureTranslation: fullTranslationY)
            delegate?.onOverflow(delta: delta)
        case .off:
            return
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 { // scrollview B is at the top
            // if the overflow is starting : initilize
            if !overflowState.isOn {
                let translation = self.customPanGesture.translation(in: self.view)
                self.overflowState = .on(lastRecordedGestureTranslation: translation.y)

                // disable scroll as we don't scroll in this scrollView from now on
                scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true // so that both the pan gestures on scrollview will be triggered
    }
}
```

GlobalViewController :

```
//
//  GlobalViewController.swift
//  Sandbox
//
//  Created by Eric Blachère on 23/12/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Eric Blachère. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class GlobalViewController: UIViewController, OverflowDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewA: UIScrollView!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "secondSegue", let ctrl = segue.destination as? ProfileDetailViewController else {
            return
        }
        ctrl.delegate = self
    }

    func onOverflowEnded() {
        // scroll to top if at least one third of the overview is showed (you can change this fraction as you please ^^)
        let shouldScrollToTop = (scrollViewA.contentOffset.y <= 2 * scrollViewA.frame.height / 3)
        if shouldScrollToTop {
            scrollViewA.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollViewA.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollViewA.contentSize.height - 1, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)
        }
    }

    func onOverflow(delta: CGFloat) {
        // move the scrollview content
        if scrollViewA.contentOffset.y - delta <= scrollViewA.contentSize.height - scrollViewA.frame.height {
            scrollViewA.contentOffset.y -= delta
            print("difference : \(delta)")
            print("contentOffset : \(scrollViewA.contentOffset.y)")
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : ProfileOverviewViewController & ProfileDetailViewController are set in the GlobalViewController in a storyboard via container views but it should work as well if set in code ;)

Comment: Thanks, this works really well! I made a few extra changes so that the user can scroll up past the end of ScrollViewB to trigger the scroll in ScrollViewA and then scroll back down and continue scrolling in ScrollViewB, all in the same gesture.

Apologies but I misunderstood the answer of another user and I therefore cannot offer you the bounty however this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example with a slightly modified version of the structure listed by OP. I've updated the structure here:

```
- UIPageViewController
      - UIViewController (ProfileOverviewViewController)
      - UIViewController (ProfileDetailViewController)
            - UICollectionView (ScrollViewB)
```

We've replaced the parent view controller, which contained a scroll view, with an instance of a [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller). The purpose for this change was to gain the pagination functionality, and the [UIPageViewControllerDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource) & [UIPageViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate) functions as well.

---

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// MARK: - ScrollViewAController

final class ScrollViewAController : UIPageViewController {

    private var _viewControllers: [UIViewController] = []

    convenience init(viewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        self.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .vertical, options: nil)
        self._viewControllers = viewControllers
        dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setViewControllers([_viewControllers.first!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: UIPageViewControllerDataSource

extension ScrollViewAController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let viewControllers = _viewControllers
        guard let index = _viewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil // view controller not found
        }

        let previousIndex = index - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return nil // index is invalid
        }

        guard viewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil // previous index is invalid
        }

        return viewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let viewControllers = _viewControllers
        guard let index = viewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil // view controller not found
        }

        let nextIndex = index + 1
        let viewControllersCount = viewControllers.count
        guard viewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            return nil // next index is out-of-bounds (we're at the last page)
        }

        guard viewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil // next index is invalid
        }

        return viewControllers[nextIndex]
    }
}

// MARK: - ProfileOverviewViewController

final class ProfileOverviewViewController : UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "ProfileOverviewViewController"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        view.addSubview(label)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        self.view = view
    }
}

// MARK: - ProfileDetailViewController

final class ProfileDetailViewController : UIViewController {

    var scrollViewB: UIScrollView! // should be a collection view, but simplified for this sample.

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "ProfileDetailViewController"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        view.addSubview(label)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        scrollViewB = UIScrollView()
        scrollViewB.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(scrollViewB)

        scrollViewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        scrollViewB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        scrollViewB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        let scrollViewBLabel = UILabel()
        scrollViewBLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        scrollViewBLabel.text = "ScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\nScrollViewB\n"
        scrollViewBLabel.textAlignment = .center
        scrollViewBLabel.textColor = .white
        scrollViewB.addSubview(scrollViewBLabel)

        scrollViewBLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollViewBLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewB.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewBLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewB.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewBLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewB.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewBLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1500).isActive = true
        scrollViewBLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewB.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        self.view = view
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        scrollViewB.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 2000)
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = [
    ProfileOverviewViewController(),
    ProfileDetailViewController(),
]

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ScrollViewAController(viewControllers: viewControllers)
```

Comment: That's really neat! Why does it work with `UIPageViewController` and not `UIScrollView`?

Comment: @jacobsieradzki it would work with a `UIScrollView` as well, however, I had made the change to a `UIPageViewController` for other benefits like lazy instantiation of the paging view controllers, and a specific API for dealing with scrolling/paging through VCs.

Comment: I've realised that the example worked in Playgrounds but didn't actually answer the question. Apologies but marking this correct answer was a mistake (I had thought that the `UIPageViewController` automatically solved my issue).

Comment: @jacobsieradzki If I understand correctly this solves the problem only in Playground live preview ? (I only tested this in playground & it seemed to work)

Comment: The problem works in the Playground that you provided and I thought the solution to the problem was to use UIPageViewController rather than UIScrollView. However, since you said that this is not the case, then this does not address the issue in the question and you have essentially recreated my view hierarchy. When implementing your recreation in my own project later, it hadn't solved the problem that was asked.

Comment: @jacobsieradzki okay, I don't have a computer with me at the moment (I'm on vacation), but I'll update this answer with another working version. Could you explain which problem this solution doesn't solve? I'm not sure what isn't working from your comment above. Thanks!